# Express server can't recieve auth headers sent by angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, express, http, authentication, jwt

I'm creating an app where the user can login and see its profile. To do that I have enpdpoint on the server:

```
router.get('/profile',
passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}),
async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.headers)
    try {
        let users = await usersDB.getAll();
        res.json({
            users: users,
            user: req.user
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);

    }   
});
```

Here the line `passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false})` should authenticate the user if there is auth token in the header. 
But as far as I try to log headers - they don't have such field.
so on login button submit i do following :

```
 public onLoginSubmit(): void {
    const user = {
      email : this.email,
      password : this.password
    }
    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe((data: any)=>{
      if(data.success){//here need to check response for success
        this.authService.storeUserData(data);
        this.router.navigate(['/user']);
      }else{
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    });
 }
```

then have a look on getProfile():

```
    getProfile(){
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      this.loadToken();
      headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Authorization', this.authToken);
      return this.http.get(`${this.url}profile/`, {headers:headers})
      .pipe(map(res => res))
    }
```

Well, when sending the request I'm getting `401 Unauthorized`
But with postman everything works pretty fine . Here is the code from postman:

```
GET /profile HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
: 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.iDt1lE5CziA05Wd2s1y536S0LyahGCRmwe6WsgYytzQ
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5c4e2375-d8d0-43a0-87f8-25cd9a85c92f
```

Comment: Check network/tab and logs for errors and check what data is sent/received. Maybe you also have some cors issue?

Comment: @David, I've done that twice. The problem is that I can't see token in request headers

Comment: I see nowhere in your code where you add the token to the API request

Comment: @David, sorry, updated the post (pasted right method)

Comment: Well, as the answer below indicated, it's because `HttpHeaders` is immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpHeaders are inmutable so just try(I guess you dont need to set application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

```
     getProfile(){
      let headers = new HttpHeaders({
'Authorization' : this.authToken
});
      this.loadToken();
      return this.http.get(`${this.url}profile/`, {headers:headers})
      .pipe(map(res => res))
    }
```

If your auth is Bearer you will need 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+'this.authToken'